# removing a css style with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have normal HTML input fields, that have default borders depending on Window/Browser settings.

During form validation I set the border of elements to red. for Example

```
elem.style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
```

If the user corrects the input, I want to remove the red border, so that the input field contains again the
default border.

Comment: Can't jQuery cure famine and stop wars? Just what I have heard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easier if you just toggle the class.

```
       var addClass = function( c, e ) {
        e.className += ' ' + c;
        },

        removeClass = function( c, e ) {
        e.className = e.className.replace( c, '' );
        };
```

Usage:

```
addClass( 'redBorder', el);
removeClass( 'redBorder', el);
```

CSS:

```
.redBorder { border:1px solid red; }
```

Comment: awesome solution, for once someone did it the old fashioned way +1

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing it is adding a CSS class to set the border. You can add a class as

```
.redBorder{
  border: "1px solid #FF0000";
}
```

And whenever you need to set this class, you can add this as the class for the element. This will ease the process of resetting the same.

Answer (score 1):

In non-IE browsers, you can use the `removeProperty()` method of the `style` object:

```
elem.style.removeProperty("border");
```

However, it makes more sense to add and remove a CSS class, as Kangkan suggested, since this will work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways depending on your needs or possibilities to add css

replacing the class is a better solution overall in case of multiple classes - see other answers for example

```
<style>
.red { border:1px solid red }
.black { border:1px solid black }
</style>

<input class="black" type="text" onKeyUp="this.className = isNaN(this.value)?'red':'black'">
<input class="black" type="text" onKeyUp="this.style.border = isNaN(this.value)?'1px solid red':'1px solid black'">
```